# How to check that user is writing text in any app in android

Tags: android

Is there any method or way to check that user is writing text whether in whatsapp, or messaging, or any edit text.

Comment: Try using TextWatcher for edittext in android.

Comment: Looking to make a password stealer or spam or spy app ? This is the not the place to look for such guidance help.

Comment: You can monitor text in your activity edittext using TextWatcher, not from someone else's app.

Comment: No I am not making password stealer app.... I am making a custom keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

No, not supported by Android. It might be possible if you go on a lower level using NDK, but the short answer is, there is no easy way.

The basis of this answer is how Java works, each application runs in a virtual environment and thus they can not interact with each other directly.

If you really want to achieve this (However there will probably be limited usage, such as only rooted devices) I would suggest to start search the web with `keylogger` `android` as keywords.